# Element is not clickable with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get data from website.
Since it is dynamically loaded and sometimes it takes 1-2 minutes for 1 elements to load "time.sleep(1..2...3...10)" doesnt work, because it closes itself earlier. ("Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable with Selenium and Python")
My code is as below:

```
import os
import platform

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

if platform.system() == "Windows":
    try:
        import undetected_chromedriver
        from parsel import Selector
        from selenium import webdriver
    except ImportError:
        os.system('python -m pip install parsel')
        os.system('python -m pip install selenium')
        os.system('python -m pip install undetected_chromedriver')
else:
    try:
        from parsel import Selector
        from selenium import webdriver
        import undetected_chromedriver
    except ImportError:
        os.system('python3 -m pip install parsel')
        os.system('python3 -m pip install selenium')
        os.system('python3 -m pip install undetected_chromedriver')

import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import csv
import os
from parsel import Selector
import time
from selenium import webdriver

filename = "cadastre"

if __name__ == '__main__':

    driver = uc.Chrome()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get("https://kais.cadastre.bg/bg/Map")
    input("Ready (Y/N) : ")

    if filename+'.csv' not in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        with open(filename+".csv","a",newline="",encoding="utf-8") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
        
    while True:
        print("Waiting for 3 sec")
        time.sleep(3)
        response = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
        uids = response.xpath('.//*[@id="resultsList"]//@data-uid').extract()
        print(uids)
        for uid in uids:
            print("Clicking : "+str(uid))
            driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='.//*[@data-uid="'+str(uid)+'"]/a').click()
            time.sleep(1)

        for uid in uids:
            sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source).xpath('.//*[@data-uid="'+str(uid)+'"]')
            textfile = ','.join([i.strip() for i in sel.xpath('.//*[@class="object-properties"]/p//text()').extract() if i.strip()])

            if textfile:
                with open(filename+".csv","a",newline="",encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    writer = csv.writer(f)
                    writer.writerow([textfile])
                    print([textfile])

        current_page = Selector(text=driver.page_source).xpath('.//*[@id="resultsList_pager"]//*[@class="k-link k-pager-nav"]/text()').extract_first()
        if Selector(text=driver.page_source).xpath('.//*[@data-page="'+str(int(current_page)+1)+'"]'):
            driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('k-link k-pager-nav')[8].click();")
        else:
            break


    driver.close()
```

I have searching through all possible ways to do the WebDriverWait, but all options did not work.

Comment: better show URL for this page so we could see how it works. OR even better create minimal working code so we could copy and test it.

Comment: Тhis is the whole code, but for it to work you need to open the map and select buildings after it opens your browser (I edit it in question)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from time import sleep

counter = 1

aa = ""

while counter < 100:
    try:
        aa = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='resultsList']//@data-uid")
    except:
        print("Element not visible yet...")

    if "selenium" in str(aa):
        print("Element located!")
        break

    sleep(1)
    counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which element makes problem.
And code makes problem only when it clicks to show details.
(but I tested on `Firefox` instead of `undetected_chromedriver`)

When it clicks to open details then it moves other elements and they are not visible in window - so Selenium can't click them.

I had to use `javaScript` to click it

```
item = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=f'.//*[@data-uid="{uid}"]/a')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', item)
```

And this way I can get all selected elements.
I got ~123 items (from ~13 pages)

---

[image]

Comment: I change it like this:

Comment: ' while uids == uidsold:
    print("Change page manually")
    response = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
    uids = response.xpath('.//*[@id="resultsList"]//@data-uid').extract()
    time.sleep(1)
print(uidsold)
uidsold = response.xpath('.//*[@id="resultsList"]//@data-uid').extract()
for uid in uids:
    counter = 1
    print("Clicking : "+str(uid))
    while counter < 2:
        try:
            driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='.//*[@data-uid="'+str(uid)+'"]/a').click()
            counter = counter + 1
        except:
          time.sleep(1)
          print("Wait") '

Comment: @AzPakAz if you resolved your problem then you can put it as answer. If you have some new information then you can append code to your question and describe changes - code will be more readable in question.

Answer (score 0):

I write the following scripts, can grap all data:need check whether the data is empty;need check loading image disappear before grap the data of current page;need check whether it is the last page.

```
from time import sleep
from clicknium import clicknium as cc

if not cc.chrome.extension.is_installed():
    cc.chrome.extension.install_or_update()
tab = cc.chrome.attach_by_title_url(url='https://kais.cadastre.bg/bg/Map')
results = tab.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultsList"]')

while True:
    elems = results.find_elements_by_xpath('./div')
    for elem in elems:
        elem.find_element_by_xpath('./a[1]').click()
        while True:
            property = elem.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="object-properties"]/p').get_text()
            if property == None:
                sleep(0.1)
            else:
                print(property)
                break
    if tab.is_existing_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultsList_pager"]//a[@class="k-link k-pager-nav"]//span[@class="k-icon k-i-arrow-e"]'):
        tab.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultsList_pager"]//a[@class="k-link k-pager-nav"]//span[@class="k-icon k-i-arrow-e"]').click()
        tab.wait_disappear_by_xpath('//div[@class="k-loading-image"]')
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem with these change:

```
while True:
    print("Waiting for 1 sec")
    time.sleep(1)
    response = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
    uids = response.xpath('.//*[@id="resultsList"]//@data-uid').extract()
    while uids == uidsold:
        print("Change the Chrome page manually !")
        response = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
        uids = response.xpath('.//*[@id="resultsList"]//@data-uid').extract()
        time.sleep(1)
    print(uidsold)
    uidsold = response.xpath('.//*[@id="resultsList"]//@data-uid').extract()
    for uid in uids:
        counter = 1
        print("Clicking : "+str(uid))
        while counter < 2:
            try:
                driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='.//*[@data-uid="'+str(uid)+'"]/a').click()
                time.sleep(1)
                counter = counter + 1
            except:
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Wait")
```